# fullcalendar removing header still shows small cell

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to remove the header in my dayview in my fullcalendar plugin. using

```
columnFormat: {day: false},
```

removes the text but it still leaves a small empty cell! how can I remove this?

[image http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/1994/fullcal.png](http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/1994/fullcal.png)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 26):

You can hide header by config like this

header:false

Answer (score 10):

You can add the config like this.

```
headerToolbar: false
```

refer to [this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/headerToolbar)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.fc-toolbar').remove();
```